# Scroll to top only on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll

I want to get to the top of the page but only on mobile, not in window/computer.

This is the code I use:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
    }
});

$('.scrollup').click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
});
```

Does anybody now how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

This code should detect most mobile browsers.

```
$('.scrollup').click(function () {
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Check out this answer for some more info: [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

Answer (score -1):

The above methods didn't work for me on mobile browsers: then I used the below code and worked properly:

first, need to define an id for your page container as body-container then:

```
document.getElementById('body-container').scrollTo(0, 0)
```

in angular I put this code in router.events to trigger it after any routing:

```
router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
   document.getElementById('body-container').scrollTo(0, 0)
}
```